# How to create USB Ubuntu boot disk in OS X so that it boots on *non-Apple* computer?

Tags: usb, startup, unix

While this seems like a straight forward task, the few methods I've tried so far don't create a USB device that my Dell computer will recognize as a valid bootable USB drive.

Here's what I've tried so far (using a cheap 2gb thumb drive, along with the 64-bit Ubuntu Desktop 13.10 ISO from Ubuntu's website):

1. Insert USB drive, and format it to MS-FAT32 using Disk Utility; then follow this [How to create a bootable USB stick on OS X](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx) Ubuntu guide <strike>verbatim</strike> *(**update:** I wasn't as verbatim as I thought! see comment under accepted answer)*.
2. Insert USB drive with existing formatting; open [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/), using the same ISO, create a USB installer disk.

In both cases, when I explicitly tell my Dell computer to boot from the "USB Device", I get an error along the lines of "Can't find valid boot disk; press F1 to try again".

I ended up creating the boot disk with the same ISO using a different computer running Ubuntu, using the [Startup Disk Creator](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/usb-creator-gtk/) -- thus I have confidence the ISO is fine -- but I'm stuck wondering, how can I do this with my OS X computer (currently with 10.8.5)?

Comment: You might also use `dd` like needed to prepare a disk for Raspberry Pi - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/122538/how-to-erase-and-reformat-sd-card-to-ext3-on-my-macbook-to-prepare-it-for-my-ras

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me it has always worked (albeit building Mint install usb pen drives DOS MBR partitioned) using Terminal , and as per the instructions on the Linux Mint website (http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/744), which I copy below:

> Using the Terminal
>
> It is really simple. Go to a Terminal and type:
>
> sudo dd if=~/Desktop/linuxmint.iso of=/dev/sdx oflag=direct  bs=1048576
>   Where '~/Desktop/linuxmint.iso' is the name and location of your downloaded image (located at the desktop in this example) and '/dev/sdx' is the target USB drive. If your system doesn't support 'oflag=direct', you can just leave it out as it is simply intended to speed up the process a bit.
>
> Remember, don't include an integer for the USB drive, e.g. '/dev/sdx1', as it would refer to the existing partition on that drive and not the drive itself.
>
> When the USB has been properly created by 'dd', there should be an output similar to this:
>
> sudo dd if=~/Desktop/linuxmint.iso of=/dev/sdb oflag=direct bs=1048576
>
> 706+1 records in
>
> 706+1 records out
>
> 740601856 bytes (741 MB) copied, 91.7024 s, 8.1 MB/s

Hope it helps

Comment: After looking at your post, I realized that I was including the partition number, so I guess the data was copying over fine but the bootloader was not being set. Thanks for helping find the error of my ways!

Comment: didn't work for me. I also want to create a bootable USB flash drive with Ubuntu in MacOX and then use this to install on Dell laptop

Comment: @siddhusingh maybe you could be a bit more explicit. Just "didn't work for me" is a tad short. I have used this method on a number of Dell and HP hardware.

Comment: @cucu8, sorry for brevity over clarity :). Basically I had put .iso file ( Ubuntu image ) on pen drive and while booting I tried to install it from the pen drive. It didn't find it as image.

Comment: @siddhusingh just plain copying the .iso image onto the pen drive will *not* work. You have to use dd, as explained above.

Comment: @cucu8, I did that as well, still didn't solve the issue. It is getting recognized as bootable drive. I ran the command in Mac using terminal

Comment: @siddhusingh you say: "Its getting recognised as a bootable drive..." Is it? or Is it not? If it is, and assuming the dd process in the Mac ended successfully, what does the Dell say?

Comment: @cucu8, I do apologize. It is not getting recognised as bootable drive.

Comment: @siddhusingh Is the Dell box configured (via setup at boot) to boot from USB? You need to go into the BIOS setup when the box is powering up (via F2 or F8 or something, I do not remember) and check there that it *will* boot from USB.

Comment: @cucu8 yes I did the same. Still it is not recognising it as bootabke device. I can install using CD though.