# mkfs.jffs2 or equivalence on Mac Os X

Tags: homebrew, filesystem, command-line

I need to use `mkfs.jffs2` command on Mac OS X. On Linux, the command is installed with `mtd-tools` package, but I can't find it from `homebrew`.

I tried to build from the source, but I have numerous compilation errors including some linux headers, so I didn't try further.

I also found http://wiki.openmoko.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X#mkfs.jffs2, but the link is gone.

I installed e2fsprogs with `brew install e2fsprogs` from [How to erase and reformat SD card to ext3 on my macbook to prepare it for my raspberry pi](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/122538/how-to-erase-and-reformat-sd-card-to-ext3-on-my-macbook-to-prepare-it-for-my-ras), but it installs only `mkfs.extX` commands.

Why there seems to be no `mkfs.jffs2` on Mac OS X? Is there any equivalence on Mac OS X?

Comment: You have asked the same question (now deleted) on StackOverflow a few months ago without getting any answer, so it might just be that no implementation of jffs2 for recent OS X exists.

Comment: @patrix: That's my understanding. I just wanted to know if there are possible alternatives.